# Whats the best way to including Header Footer in PHP?

Tags: php, html, header

If I want to include header file on a page, whats the best way to create header.php  file?

Should I include this section of the html to my header.php file so it shows up on every page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
```

Or should I only include navbar content in the header.php?

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, it can depend on all sorts of things from if you are using a javascript framework or a PHP template engine.

Comment: "best" is subjective. Do whatever suits your situation. Is this approach giving you any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a few years ago by Harvard's CS50 class:

```
function render($template, $values = array()){

   // if template exists, render it    
   if (file_exists("../views/$template")){    

      // extract variables into local scope    
      extract($values);    

      // render header_form    
      require("../views/header_form.php");    

      // render template    
      require("../views/$template");    

      // render footer    
      require("../views/footer_form.php");

   }else{

      // else err    
      trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);

   }    
}
```

make sure your header has <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body> and your footer has closing </body></html>

As far as whether or not to include navigation in the header it depends on whether or not you want every page to have the same navigation

Comment: Hey, thanks thats helpful. What about this, when I include <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body> then I include page title as well, but page title should be unique to the page, or shouldn’t it? My other question was can my header.php file have a separate css file? At the moment I have it that way and although it works all fine I wasn’t sure if that the best practice.

Comment: you can do something like  <head><?php echo  $title; ?></head>  or pass $title in $values and use innerText or innerHTML and yes it's fine to have a separate css for your header.  Please accept answer if it works for you.